# How to change color of text in rows with DataBinder

Tags: c#, asp.net, colors, databinder

I want to change color of text in specific column in each of rows. I have several columns, one of them is named *DeliverState* which can obtain one of two states - *"Delivered"* or *"NotDelivered"*

```
<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "dbs").ToString()=="1" ? "" : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "deliver_state")%></td>
```

I want to change color of the text *(which can be Delivered or NotDelivered)* in each row in column *DeliverState* to green if *"Delivered"* and red if *"NotDelivered"*.

What is the best way to do it in .aspx file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe add a class to the items based on your if condition? that way you can add a styling for  e.g

```
.NotDelivered
{ 
  color:Red
}

.Delivered
{
   color:Green
}


<td class="<%#Evaluated your choice : "delivered" : "notDelivered"><...the rest of your statement ..></td>
```

I would maybe suggest that you put the eval into a a variable that you can call on evaluation of the tenary operator.

Comment: this will be on the <td class="<%#Evaluated your choice : "delivered" : "notDelivered"><...the rest of your statement

I would maybe suggest that you put the eval into a a variable that you can call twice as opposed to evaluating the same expression twice